# Deriving subsets from a given set whose union gives back the given set.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

> Let $S=\{1,2,3...,n\}$ and let $T$ be the set of all ordered triples of subsets of $S$, say $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$, such that $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3=S$. Determine, in terms of $n$, $$\sum_{(A_1,A_2,A_3\in T)} |A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3|$$
>   where $|X|$ denotes the number of elements in the set $X$.

I am trying to derive a formula for number of subsets from a given set whose union gives back the given set. Example: if $S=\{ 1,2,3 \}$, then $\{ 1\},\{2\},\{3\}$ ....(1), $\{ 1\},\{2,3\},\{3\}$ ....(2), $\{ 1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,2\}$ ....(3) etc.

Comment: Have you been able to compute this value for small values of $n$?

Comment: No, not yet, please help!

Comment: Perhaps take a look at chains and anti-chains. Mirsky's theorem states that the minimum number of anti-chains that partition a set S is the largest chain in a partial order. The key part here is using the idea that the anti-chains partition the set S (In here we are looking at a anti-chain with sets $A_1,A_2,A_3$ and all we have to count is the largest chain to find this and then go on from here with dependence on the definition of the partial order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make $n$ a variable give the sets $T$ and $S$ the index $n$.

Then:

$$\begin{aligned}\sum_{\langle A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\in T_{n}\rangle}|A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}| & =\sum_{\langle A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\rangle\in T_n}\sum_{k\in S_n}1_{A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}}(k)\\
 & =\sum_{k\in S_n}\sum_{\langle A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\rangle\in T_n}1_{A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}}(k)\\
 & =n\sum_{\langle A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\rangle\in T_n}1_{A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}}(n)\\
 & =n\left|\left\{ \langle A_{1},A_{2},A_{3}\rangle\in T_{n}\mid n\in A_{1}\cap A_{2}\cap A_{3}\right\} \right|\\
 & =n\left|\left\{ \langle B_{1},B_{2},B_{3}\rangle\in\wp(S_{n-1})^3\mid\langle B_{1}\cup\left\{ n\right\} ,B_{2}\cup\left\{ n\right\} ,B_{3}\cup\left\{ n\right\} \rangle\in T_{n}\right\} \right|\\
 & =n\left|T_{n-1}\right|
\end{aligned}
$$

The third equality is based on symmetry.

What remains is finding an expression for $\left|T_{n}\right|$.

Can you do that yourself?

Hint: for every $k\in S_n$ we have the set $\{i\in\{1,2,3\}\mid k\in A_i\}$.

How many of such sets are possible for each $k\in S_n$ if $\langle A_1,A_2,A_3\rangle\in T_n$?

Comment: OK, thank you for the generalized approach.